# Is there a function that will give me nth prime number?

Tags: functions, prime-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a known mathematical equation to find the nth prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257/is-there-a-known-mathematical-equation-to-find-the-nth-prime)

Is there a function, like f(n), I insert n  into the function and it outputs nth prime number? I have been trying to find a pattern between the prime numbers, 1st differences, 2nd differences, but I can't find it.

To be clear: I want something like f(x)=x^2+5 or f(x)=2.sin(x)+x^2. You know what I mean...

Comment: Yes. You've just defined it, in fact. You probably actually want some sort of [formula for primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes) (q.v.) though.

Comment: Sure.  Let $f(n)$ be the function that inputs $n$ and outputs the $n$-th prime number.  :)

Less obnoxiously, you have to be more specific about the form of the function you're looking for.  Closed-form expressions exist but are pretty computationally useless, usually relying on something like Wilson's theorem to function as a characteristic function for the primes.

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear

Comment: I think Chris's wikipedia link should answer your question sufficiently.

Answer (score -1):

Well yes, the function $f$ does *exist*, but that doesn't mean we know what it looks like.

Comment: It looks like {(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 5), (4, 7), ...}.  The OP no doubt intends a closed-form formula rather than a function, but that will depend on her/his definition of "closed-form".

Comment: Many functions exist. We just don't know of an extremely simple one. But the task is often implemented; it just requires finding and counting the primes until you reach n of them.