# Convergence of an integral over the primes

Tags: measure-theory, analytic-number-theory

Does the following integral converge? If so, is it nonzero? What can we say about the integral as $x\to \infty?$

$$\int_{I} \frac{u-u\log{p_u}}{(p_u)^2}du$$
where $I= \{p \leq x | p\text{ prime}\}$ for some $x$.

Here $p_u$ denotes the $u$:th prime

Comment: Why is it not just zero since the set of primes is discrete? Or do you really intend for it to be a sum? Or is the integral really going up to $x$ and $p_u$ is actually $p_{\lfloor u \rfloor}$ or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

for $u\ge 6$

$$u (\log (u)+\log (\log (u))-1)\le p_u\le u (\log (u)+\log (\log (u)))$$

thus
$$\frac{u(1-\log p_u)}{p_u^2}\sim -\frac{1}{u\log u}$$

see [here. First answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257/is-there-a-known-mathematical-equation-to-find-the-nth-prime)